# How to set a max timeout for Jest test running Puppeteer?

Tags: jestjs, puppeteer

Tried looking through the docs, but didn't find a way to set a max timeout for a test case. Seems like a simple feature.

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer'

test('App loads', async() => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, slowMo: 250 });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('http://localhost:3000');
  await browser.close();
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Jest's `test(name, fn, timeout)` function](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/api.html#testname-fn-timeout) can take a 3rd parameter that specifies a custom timeout.

```
test('example', async () => {
  ...
}, 1000); // timeout of 1s (default is 5s)
```

Source: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5055#issuecomment-350827560

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the timeout globally for a suite using `jest.setTimeout(10000);` in the beforeAll() function:

```
beforeAll(async () => {

    jest.setTimeout(10000); // change timeout to 10 seconds

});
```